# rqt_plot trajectory_msgs/Jointrajectory/points/velocities

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I wonder if it is possible to plot this trajectory_msgs/Jointrajectory/points/velocities in rqt_plot?

[image: image description]

I want to show the joint velocities[5], in this case -0.86621.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268539/rqt_plot-trajectory_msgs/jointrajectory/points/velocities/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rqt_plot [YOUR_TOPIC]/points/velocities[5]
```

should work (obviously, adjust the topic name).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1